# Javascript: arrays, object, sorting and prototypes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, prototype-programming

I made an array of objects and was able to sort by one of the properties of the objects (see bottom code). But I hardcoded which property to sort by (in this case "name"). How would I be able to pass to the sort method the property I am looking to sort by? I tried tmpArray.sort(function(a, b, sortBy) but got a no soup for you response. I know I can modify the array object with

```
array.prototype.thing = function(){ alert("hello world"); }
```

But is is possible for me to modify an existing method, like array.sort? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".sort").click(function() { 

    var tmpArray = new Array;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++) { 

        var tmpObject = new Object;
        switch(i) { 

            case 0 : 
                tmpObject.name = "Amy";
                tmpObject.rank = 1;
                tmpObject.priority = 3;
                tmpObject.item = "Blue Item";
                break;

            case 1 :
                tmpObject.name = "Jen";
                tmpObject.rank = 2;
                tmpObject.priority = 0;
                tmpObject.item = "Red Item";
                break;

            case 2 :
                tmpObject.name = "Mike";
                tmpObject.rank = 3;
                tmpObject.priority = 2;
                tmpObject.item = "Green Item";
                break;

            case 3 :
                tmpObject.name = "Raul";
                tmpObject.rank = 4;
                tmpObject.priority = 2;
                tmpObject.item = "Yellow Item";
                break;                      

                            case 4 :
                tmpObject.name = "Lola";
                tmpObject.rank = 5;
                tmpObject.priority = 1;
                tmpObject.item = "Blue Item";
                break;                      

        }

        tmpArray.push(tmpObject); 
    }

    tmpArray.sort(function(a, b) {
             var nameA=a.name.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.name.toLowerCase()

        if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
            return -1
        if (nameA > nameB)
            return 1

        return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
        });

        console.log(tmpArray);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick example, something like this should work. `arr` being the Array to sort, `key` being the Object key to use. Mind you, this is only one level deep sorting.

```
var arr = [
    {"one" : Math.random(), "two" : Math.random(), "id" : "First"},
    {"one" : Math.random(), "two" : Math.random(), "id" : "Second"},
    {"one" : Math.random(), "two" : Math.random(), "id" : "Third"}
];

var oSort = function (arr, key) {
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        a = a[key], b = b[key];
        return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
    });
};

oSort(arr, 'two');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XwswP/

Edit to answer

> But is is possible for me to modify an existing method, like array.sort? Thanks.

Yes it's possible, but don't do that. If you wanted to overwrite it, you could do
`Array.prototype.sort = function() { ...`

Comment: Thanks Robert, that worked exactly as I needed. I didn't intend on messing with the array method, I figured I do that and then break the whole internets and then everyone is mad at me... : D

Answer (score 1):

You can write `a[someString]` to get the property named in the `someString` variable.

Answer (score -1):

Your sort seems to be working fine here:

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/2nFYN/

Comment: "How would I be able to pass to the sort method the property I am looking to sort by?"

Comment: @mellammokb -- im not sure why ur quoting that

Comment: Um.. because that's what the OP wants to do??  You just copied the OP's code into jsfiddle and posted an answer.  The OP already knows the code works.